# How to design a service without having to pass values ​to the method?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, doctrine

I want to do a manipulation after a setter in a class.
I want, for example to use the `LoggerInterface` or `EntityManagerInterface`.

exemple:

```
public function setSlug(?string $slug): self
    {
        if ($this->slug !== $slug) {
            $sr = new SaveRedirection();
            $sr->saveRedirection();
        }
        $this->slug =  $slug;
}
```

If the slug needs to be changed, I wish I could save it. For this I want a saveRedirection service.

```
class SaveRedirection  {

 public function saveRedirection() {
        $this->logger->info('Transforming ');
}
```

My problem is that I don't have a logger or manager to send it from my class (therefore from the setter) to the service.

I don't know how to access the logger or the EntityManagerInterface.

I don't want to change the setter of my class so I don't want to do this:

```
 public function setSlug(?string $slug, EntityManagerInterface $em): self
```

If I put it directly in the constructor of my service I get this error message:

> Too few arguments to function App\Service\SaveRedirection::__construct(), 0 passed in

How to make the Service take care of LoggerInterface or EntityManagerInterface on its own without being given the values ​​during: `$sr->saveRedirection();` ?

Or am I mistaken in logic and I have to use a listener to do this?

Comment: Search for how to globally access the Symfony container.  It's not recommended that you do this but sometimes it's the easiest approach.

Comment: Hi, is not the best way to inject in a `entity` somethig like the logger. The best way is to use the doctrine events to listen changes on this field and do something about that... https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use Doctrine `EventSubscriber`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function __construct(SaveRedirection $sr)
    {
        $this->sr = $sr;
    }
    
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        //implement some action here
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::onFlush,
        ];
    }
}
```

You will need probably to register the subscriber in `services.yml`

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...

    App\EventListener\EntitySubscriber:
        tags:
            - name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber'
```

There are other possible events described in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers

Comment: While using globals is bad, using some sort of workaround like this is, in my not so humble opinion, far worse.

Comment: I can't get it to work...I don't understand why

Comment: ``use App\Entity\CategorieBlogPost;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

class EasyAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {

    private $slugger;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(SluggerInterface $slugger, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->slugger = $slugger;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }``

Comment: public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate,
        ];
    }

Comment: public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        // if this subscriber only applies to certain entity types,
        // add some code to check the entity type as early as possible
        if (!$entity instanceof CategorieBlogPost) {
            return;
        }
        $this->logger->info('EasyAdminSubscriber');
        $this->$entity->setSlug('test1');
        $this->$entity->setNom('test2');
        dd('test');
    }

Comment: services:
    App\EventSubscriber\EasyAdminSubscriber:
        tags:
            - name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber'

Comment: @Cerad why do you think using Doctrine Events is a workaround?

Comment: @Camel4488 what is `$this->entity` in your case? shouldn't you work on `$entity`?

Anyway, you need to change the doctrine changeSet,

More on how to modify the entity using `preUpdate` can be found here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/events.html#reference-events-pre-update

Comment: thank you very much. I struggled but I got there  Events::preUpdate, and public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args): void thank you !

Comment: like that I have access to the changeSet. I can check the class with the instanceof and so it meets my need well. OK, I spent hours trying to figure it out. Thank you so much for directing me!

Comment: I don't know if it's optimized or not. What is the difference between preFlush and preUpdate?

Comment: @Trutch70 As I understood the original question the goal was to access the logger (and perhaps entity manager) from inside a rather mysterious non-entity SaveRedirection class.  No idea what the class is supposed to be doing besides using the logger.  I have seen Doctrine events used to inject services into entities and it works I suppose but to me it is a hack.  However, the OP seems to be making progress with events so I'll withdraw from the discussion.  Good luck.